# How the GeneratedDuration property of VisualTransition work?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, xaml, custom-controls

I start learning WPF for a few days. Now I'm making animatable `Button` that change its appearances when it changes states using `VisualStateManager`.

Create my `Button` and apply `ControlTemplate` to it

```
<Button Content="This is a Button" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" 
    Template="{DynamicResource ButtonControlTemplate}" 
    FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" FontSize="24" Foreground="White"/>
```

Here is the `ControlTemplate`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid x:Name="ElementRoot">
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1" Width="Auto" CornerRadius="3">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF8FFF6" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF67ED38" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF52A370" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF054E21" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <ContentPresenter 
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding   HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here is the `VisualStateManager` that changes the appearances of the `Button`

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition From="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" To="Pressed">
                <Storyboard x:Name="MouseOverToPressedStoryboard">
                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="20,10"/>
                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualTransition>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
            <Storyboard x:Name="pressedStoryboard">
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border" To="#FF3DA917" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I have read the `GeneratedDuration` property detail in MSDN (here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.VISUALTRANSITION.GENERATEDDURATION%29;k%28VS.XAMLEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)) and if I understand that right, `GeneratedDuration` is the time that the control (my `Button`) takes to transition from one state to other state. In my situation is from `MouseOver` to `Pressed`. By that, it must wait for one second before it enter `Pressed` state. The Pressed state changes the background color of the Button. When you point the mouse to the Button (not click yet) and then you click it, after one second, the appearance of the `Button` should start changing. But it changes immediately when you click in it.

What and where do I misunderstand ? Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance.